# Is there a case where a ruby "exception" would get through 'rescue Object'?

Tags: ruby, exception

Is there a way for something to raise and exception that does not descend from Exception?

What I'm trying to avoid is something like:

```
require 'timeout'
begin
  timeout(1) {sleep(50)}
rescue StandardError => e
  puts e.message
end
```

I know I can catch this with 'rescue Exception' or more drastically, 'rescue Object', but that seems a little odd to me.

Comment: I assume you know that StandardError descends from Exception, and that exception is not rescued, while StandardError and its descendants are, right? It's not entirely clear from your question.

Comment: Yes, I just needed an example of an exception that would bubble through the rescue. As you said, raise barfs if you give it something that does not descend from Exception. Is that the only way an exception can be raised? Does anything raised through the C API have the same restrictions(again, I'm assuming you can raise an exception from there)

Comment: I have no idea about the C API, but I'd just assume if one manages to do something through the API that ruby itself wouldn't allow, it's an inappropriate use of the API (and maybe a bug in the API itself). So, too hypothetical. I'd just let this one pass.

Comment: I guess hypothetically is good enough for me!

Comment: Some smart alec could try raising a `BasicObject` in Ruby 1.9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you try to raise an error that's not of the `Exception` class, you'll get a `<TypeError: exception class/object expected>`.

Comment: Thanks! I was getting this error because I did `raise prefix, "my error msg"` instead of `raise prefix + "my error msg"`, where `prefix` is a string. Oops. Fixed! :)